# puppetdb: purge stockpile Command Queue

Tags: puppet

I recently tried to upgrade a one of our puppet compile masters from 4.8.2 to 5.5.10.  however our puppetDB remained on version 4.4.  This caused [a schema validation](https://phabricator.wikimedia.org/T230002) similar to the one reported in  [PDB-3743](https://tickets.puppetlabs.com/browse/PDB-3743).  I have since reverted the change however i am now left with a command Queue of 2k+.

Inspecting the stockpile directory `/var/lib/puppetdb/stockpile/cmd/q`. I can see that all of the files in the queue are reports from hosts using which used the upgraded puppet master and they all have a `job_id: null` value.

Could anyone enlighten me on how to purge this queue.  Moving files out of this directory does not make the queue go down.  Further when does the queue runner try to reprocess the files in its queue and can one manually force this. I only ever see a stack trace for the first time the report is submitted suggesting that the queue runner never attempts to re-process theses reports.

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question i was able to clear down the queue by shutting down puppetdb and removing all the files from `/var/lib/puppetdb/stockpile/cmd/q`.  i further noticed that puppetdb will try to re-process any files in `/var/lib/puppetdb/stockpile/cmd/q` when it starts up.